# Way to organize database changes tracking in c# code

Tags: c#, database, architecture

I'm developing e-commerce system, at the moment I do Product class, which works as container of a lot of entities such as photos, product parameters (name value collection), etc. I know that everything here should be stored in database (ms sql).

So such use case will be popular:
1) Customer open some product to edit it
2) Customer adds couple new photos
3) Customer changes some parameters of the product
4) Customer clicks on Save button.

So the question is what is the best way to track changes made? I can calculate them in repository class by comparing data in class to be saved and the same class just loaded from db, but it seems a bit ugly thing to do.

I also think that it's not good idea to pollute Product class with this tracking code.

Comment: Which version of SQLServer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx

Comment: You may take a look at CQRS and Event-sourced application architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the change tracking with Entity Framework. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/10/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-3-change-tracking-with-poco.aspx

Comment: at the moment i don't use any ORM for the rest of the system. so all repositories work with SqlCommand, SqlReader directly. How painfull is to start using EF with new classes and slowly migrate all repositories to it in future?

Comment: Fortunately it is very easy to migrate to EF. I recommend the "database first" approach. make your existing Model classes partial so that you retain the logic you have added in them. Take a look at these. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591506 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: I actually recommend the code first approach. Especially for a new project. The code is easier to change than the database. Plus I assume you have better version control on your code than schema.

Comment: @Aron Using database first or code first approach is a personal preference and there is a lot of debate going on over them. I recommended database first approach in this case since most developers with experience in building systems without ORM are more comfortable with the database first approach at least until they get used to EF. Also the schema is not supposed to be changed often.

Answer (score 1):

You describing [UnitOfWork pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)
There are existed implementations of this pattern for EntitiFramework ([example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)) and 
NHibernate ([example](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx)).

Comment: at the moment i don't use any ORM for the rest of the system. so all repositories work with SqlCommand, SqlReader directly. How painfull is to start using EF with new classes and slowly migrate all repositories to it in future?

Comment: Answer will really depend on your background. If you are not familiar with any orm, then it could be rather painful. If you familiar with some orm, you may try to utilize it. Otherwise you may look at EF, it is documented a bit better than NH.